# How can I rewrite this LINQ statement to handle location variable condition?

Tags: c#, linq

```
public IQueryable<JobLevelsWithJobCountViewModel> JobLevelsWithJobCountViewModels(string location = null)
{
    return (from jl in _dbContext.JobLevels
            from j in jl.Jobs
            .Where(job => job.Company.ZipCode.MajorArea.Contains(location))
            .Where(job => !job.IsDeleted && !job.IsPrivate)
            group jl by jl.JobLevelId into g
            select new JobLevelsWithJobCountViewModel
            {
                JobLevel = g.FirstOrDefault(),
                JobCount = g.FirstOrDefault().Jobs.Count(j => !j.IsDeleted && !j.IsPrivate)
            });
}
```

i don't want to add this condition **.Where(job => job.Company.ZipCode.MajorArea.Contains(location))** if location is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a short-circuiting `OR` operator to pass the condition if `location` is null:

```
.Where(job => location == null || job.Company.ZipCode.MajorArea.Contains(location))
```